# How do I debug issues with an event handler added to the window object in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I'm working on some code where I want send custom events to the window object where I have an event listener that will perform an action.  This works fine for one of the listeners, but I have a second one I want to use, but it's not registering all the time.  Is there a way to debug this as the javascript console isn't very helpful?  Or, is there a way to detect if the event listener has been added to the window object using Javascript?  If I look at the HTML element in the inspector, I can see if the event is attached or not manually.

My code looks something like this:

```
$.when($.ready).then(function () {
  // Set up the event listener to capture search terms.
  window.addEventListener('search_terms', function(evt) {
    saveSearchTerms(evt.detail);
  });
  window.addEventListener('profile-update', function(evt) {
    console.debug('got the event');
    console.debug(evt.detail);
    updateProfile(evt.detail);
  });
});
```

The firt one works fine.  It's the second one that's giving me issues.

Thanks.

Comment: It's an interesting architecture that uses the window's event dispatcher to drive application logic. At the moment, it's not really possible to establish a root cause here, but it's more likely to be at the point where `'profile-update'` is dispatched. There's almost certainly a better way to do this.

Comment: It's a minimal amount of logic, but the issue here is that the second handler is not added to the window/document, so it doesn't matter when the event is dispatched as there's nothing to receive the event.